# How to connect to server running on the system with password protection in java?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am trying to use Runtime.exec to run a class file from my java code but not able to launch the new process on Linux,The same is working on the windows..

I want or launch the process from GUI (which I am running from a jar file named Launch.jar) on a button click.

So I used the following code.

```
String curpath=System.getProperty("user.dir");
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "java -classpath"+curpath+File.separator+" Launch.jar LaunchNewProcess" });
```

Comment: what is the problem? an error occurs? an exception?

Comment: I am not getting any error or exception...it just stops..

Comment: Read and implement **all** the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  It will possibly solve the problem, if not it will give a lot more information about ***how*** to fix it.

Comment: the answer title does not match the answer, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to leave a space after `-classpath`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c",
"java -classpath "+curpath+File.separator+" Launch.jar LaunchNewProcess" });
```

Update: try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c",
"java -jar "+curpath+File.separator+"Launch.jar" });
```

Comment: String curpath=System.getProperty("user.dir");
String cmd="java -classpath "+curpath+File.separator+"Launch.jar LauchNewProcess";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", cmd);
pb.start();
Still the problem is there,I am able to run using the "java -jar Launch.jar" but not directly with the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

put a space after -classpath  and also remove space on " Launch.jar"

```
 try{

     Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "java -classpath "+curpath+File.separator+"Launch.jar LaunchNewProcess" });

}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo,The problem is while runnig from the jar file it is not working,if i am running the jar file as "java -jar Launch.jar" it is working fine.
but when i am running the jar file without the command ,it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I suggest you to drop using Runtime.exec and start using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

There are many examples/tutorials out there, [here's one](http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/getting-started-with-javas-processbuilder-a-sample-utility-class-to-interact-with-linux-from-java-program/)